# How to enable autocomplete when connect to docker container through CLI?

Tags: python, docker, terminal

I created a docker image for my FastAPI application then I created a container from that image. Now When I connect to that container using `docker exec -it <container-id>` through my terminal, I am able to access it but the problem is that autocomplete doesn't work when I press TAB.

Comment: which tool are you looking for autocompletion for? you may need to set it up when the docker image is built.

Comment: @zyxue Like for example when I want to autocomplete a file name

Comment: This doesn't especially seem like a programming question as you've described it.  What specifically are you trying to debug inside a running container?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I have understood from your question is when you enter into the docker environment, you are unable to autocomplete filenames and folders.

Usually when you enter into the container via shell, the autocomplete not works properly. Tried to enter into the container using bash environment i.e., `docker exec -it <container-id> bash`. Now you can use TAB to autocomplete files and folders.